# Fast subtitle workflow in Sony Vegas?

Tags: editing, video-editor, vegas-pro, subtitles

In Vegas is quite time consuming having to insert text using only visual cues, for example:

1. Inserting new text media requires to choose presets instead of having a default style on the go.
2. No keyboard shortcut for "Insert Text Media..."
3. Copying and pasting existing Text in the timeline requires clicking on the "Generated Media..." icon to start editing the new instance.

Is there a way to simplify or speed-up this process?

Keyboard shortcuts, third party plugins? Please give your thoughts.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vegas you can make a default text or preset by using the save preset feature. For instance you may add a text at the end of all your movies that looks like this:

Joe Blow Productions

Copyright Joe Blow 2014

After you make this text, give the text title a unique name "Joe Blow", then click the save preset button just to the right of the title window--looks like a floppy disk. The next time you go to the text generator it will be in the menu. Note, when you save any effect or text preset in Vegas you have to leave the current menu and then return to it so it refreshes the content of that menu.

Here is a short Vegas Tutorial to show you how to make your own presets:

Let's say you want to change the font of this preset, engage it, and then make your changes and save this new version with a unique name, like "Joe Blow 2".

You can do this with effects too. It's an easy way to build a custom library of effects and texts that you can use a baseline and then tweak/save as you need them.

Comment: Sure presets are very useful, but the default preset (Sample Text) can't be changed and it's also time consuming to pick presets in the drop down menu.

Comment: Probably you missed the point two of the question "1. Inserting new text media requires to choose presets instead of having a default style on the go."

Comment: Creating my own library of presets has improved my workflow, guess that's too much trouble for you.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's a point that was already mentioned, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Vegas' text capabilities are rather limited. It allows you to insert captions only one by one.

There is an extension for Vegas Pro, which is called **Vegasaur**. It contains *Text Generation Wizard* that can import text from subtitle files (srt, sub etc.) or just from the Clipboard

http://vegasaur.com/Vegasaur

Comment: Vegas is quite fast at cropping and moving text media in the timeline, str closed captioning software is rather primitive as far as I know. What do you suggest to use along with Vegasaur for subtitles?

Answer (score 0):

## Use "animate text"

Here's my workflow.

1. Play video and tap "M" letter on you keyboard to insert markers in
   places where you need your subtitles
2. Insert generated media, change it's duration to longer
3. Use the "animate" button
4. Change the keyframe transition to "hold" so that texts are not moving
5. Choose "sync cursor to media timeline"
6. Move your timeline cursor to different markers and just enter a different text in the media generator. You can use Ctrl+Arrow Right to jump to next marker

See this video that helped me to figure this out